# Android volley singleton getInstance(this) fails when performing a http request

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Am new to android and i have just checked out volley android library and i want to use it in my custom http request bu this fails with error in android studio at .getInstance

I have tried the following

So am using android studio  and have the following folder structure

```
com.geowan .....

 frontend
      1.LoginActivity

 helpers
      ApiSingleTon
```

So in my ApiSingleton i have

```
public class ApiSingleton {

  private static ApiSingleton mInstance;
  private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
  private static Context mCtx;
  private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

  private ApiSingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
     ....stuff copy pasted from volley docs on IMage disc cache loader
}


   public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
     if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

}

Now to my java login code i have

```
ApiSingleton singleton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            trylogin(); //login method
        }
    });

}

 tryLogin(){ //trying to emulate a http request
    //proceed with authentication
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, loginurl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                    Log.i(TAG, error.toString());
                }
            });

   }
       singleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest); //fails
```

The above throws an error at

```
singleton.getInstance(this)
```

Where could i be going wrong.

Comment: The method getInstance() is not defined in your ApiSingleton class! Stacktrace would be helpful as well.

Comment: i see, am a newbie to java didnt pickup that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I guess you Need To Read More About Singleton

Second

```
singleton.getInstance(this)
```

this Means You Have A Function Called getInstance return the class type in your class

So I guess You Need to Add this

```
 public static synchronized AppSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mAppSingletonInstance == null) {
            mAppSingletonInstance = new AppSingleton(context);
        }
        return mAppSingletonInstance;
    }
```